# PHP not creating session

Tags: php, apache, session

I was able to create sessions on 3 days ago. The code remained unchanged. But now I can't create session. Error Message: `Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (c:\web\dev\session) in Unknown on line 0`.

If I copy the path `c:\web\dev\session` into windows run command, it opens the path so I have verified that the path exists. I also get the error: `Warning: session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in C:\Web\dev\backdoor\request.php on line 10` but I don't specify the PHP ID.

My code looks like this:

`$user_row` is a array with all the users data for the session in it.

```
session_save_path('c:\web\dev\session');
session_start();

$_SESSION['user'] = $user_row;
$_SESSION['security']['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
   $_SESSION['forwarded_for'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
       $_SESSION['security']['forwarded_for'] = false;
    }
```

I'm using Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.6

I have seen [this link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59696) but it only seems to resolve the issue if you are using IIS. I can't seem to find the solution with Apache.

I have also tried to remove the .htaccess file from my root directory.

Comment: which windows verision do you use? make shure php can WRITE into the dir .. maybe a trick could be to set the webroot not on c: root-dir

Comment: In general, you don't need to specify `session_save_path()`. Make sure Apache service user has permission to write in that folder.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache and active sessions? Also, check that Apache has permission to write in that folder. Besides,  `session_save_path()` sounds like overkill.

Comment: Im using windows 7 ultimate. I use to be able to create sessions on friday. And this morning it just fails without reason. Nothing has changed to my OS or my PHP.
I have for the sake of development given full access to my web folder to every user and group on the computer and network to ensure full compatibility of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your php session id to something and see if that works.

I had the same problem and when i set the php id to something it worked. I think its a bug or glitch in the new php version that needs to be addressed